# Previewing files on web server?

Tags: apache

I am currently browsing the files (mostly images) on our server using HTTP, in the most primitive way (a very inefficient way).

[image]

To quickly glance a file, I need to click on and open it. Then exit, onto the next file. Very inefficient.

Is there a way that I can preview these files without opening them, just like what we do on our Mac/Windows system.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Fancybox to get both a thumbnail view, and to open images without leaving the page. You can configure Apache to display your directory as a gallery, and add in thumbnails of your image into the DOM.

[Try the instructions found here](http://www.nux.ro/oldblog/archive/2012/10/Instant_image_gallery_with_Apache_s_mod_autoindex_and_fancybox.html). The demo on that page doesn't seem to be working, but the instructions do work. The instructions there don't cover adding thumbnails, but in my abbreviated instructions below I added in a step to get them:

- Download [Fancybox](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/tree/2.1)
- Create a `fancybox` directory at the root level of your site, and add the files from the Fancybox download.
- Create a fancybox.html file in the fancybox directory and load the Fancybox library and set the config options. [See the example here](http://img.nux.ro/fancybox/fancybox.txt).
- (My addition) Add a line to fancybox.html to insert a thumbnail into the Apache directory listing. Here's just a simple line you might add after line 26 in the linked example file:

  ```
      $(this).html("<img src='"+ $(this).attr('href') +"' width='200'>" + title);
  ```
- Create a .htaccess file in your image directory (and be sure .htaccess files are usable by Apache)
- Add these lines to the .htaccess file:

  ```
  Options +Indexes
  ReadmeName /fancybox/fancybox.html
  ```
- Navigate to your image directory

You can modify the Apache directory listing page to make it as pretty as you like. [See this article on styling the directory listing.](https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/) Probably any other gallery library you like could be used with a similar method, the important thing is that the `ReadmeName` option lets you inject javascript and css which you can use to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: all! The answer above is now outdated. Since I can't ask for help, how about ... a strong suggestion that someone provide a script for the current version :-)

Comment: Hi David T-G, what is outdated above? It doesn't work in Apache anymore? I can't provide a new solution myself, but maybe can point you in the right direction.